# How do I override a previously set value for `/tikz/rotate`?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I was writing my own style for a particular collection of nodes, most of which I wanted rotated in the same manner.  So I defined the following style:

```
my node style/.style={rotate=60,draw}
```

*Please note that for the sake of a MWE, this example is very minimal.*

And then I use it in a `tikzpicture` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[my node style/.style={rotate=60,draw}]
  \node (L) at (-1.5in,0) {using my node style};
  \node[my node style] (A) at (0,0) {this is node A};
  \draw[arrows=->] (L) -- (A);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But there are a few nodes for which I want essentially the same style, but a different rotation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[my node style/.style={rotate=60,draw}]
  \node (L) at (-1.5in,0) {using my node style};
  \node[my node style] (A) at (0,0) {this is node A};
  \draw[arrows=->] (L) -- (A);

  \node (M) at (-1.5in,-1in) {not the expected effect};
  \node[my node style,rotate=-60,anchor=west,text width=2in] (B) at (0,-1in) {this is node B which I expected to be rotated $-60^\circ$};
  \draw[arrows=->] (M) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which results in

[image]

Not at all what I expected.

Is this the intended effect of multiple calls to `rotate`?
Should the effect of multiple calls to `rotate` be additive?
How do I override this without having to write an entirely new key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect of the `rotate` key is additive so multiple uses of the `rotate` key result in the transformation matrix being rotated by the sum of the values given (although the rotation is not necessarily applied immediately).

The following outlines a possible mechanism for non-additive rotation:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\let\tikz@rotate@angle=\pgfutil@empty
\tikzset{%
  Rotate/.code={%
    \ifx\tikz@rotate@angle\pgfutil@empty%
      \tikz@addtransform{\pgftransformrotate{\tikz@rotate@angle}}%
    \fi%
    \def\tikz@rotate@angle{#1}%
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node style/.style={draw, Rotate=60}]
\draw [help lines] (-1,-1) grid (3,1); 
\node [node style]             at (0,0) {A};
\node [node style, Rotate=-60] at (1,0) {B};
\node [node style, Rotate=0]   at (2,0) {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is the intended result. You define a rotation for each node called `my node style`. So I would expect every node to be rotated by default. If one of all these nodes has to be rotated less or more than the others, it should be relative to the other nodes, as you defined it to be alike in the first place. This makes small rotations much easier. Especially if you do some calculations in your style definition.

I checked the same behaviour for `yshift=2cm`. The first one was raised 2 cm, the second one 4 cm. So I would dare to say that this is happening on purpose.

In order to proof my assumption, I just added the rotation key twice to one node and they add up.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rotate=10,rotate=-10,draw] (A) at (0,0) {this is node A};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In order to be flexible, I would just define a new style, say `fresh rotate`. I guess, there are more beautiful ways of defining a TikZ-value than my `\newcommand*`, but you get the idea:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\defaultRot}{60}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[my node style/.style={rotate=\defaultRot,draw}
    ,fresh rotate/.style={rotate=-\defaultRot,rotate=#1}]
    \node[my node style] (A) at (0,0) {this is node A};
    \node[my node style, fresh rotate=-60] (B) at (3,0) {this is node B};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an alternative notation. `my node style` has an argument with a default value which can be easily changed.

I don't know if `rotate` is additive.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[my node style/.style={rotate=#1,draw}, my node style/.default=60]
  \node (L) at (-1.5in,0) {using my node style};
  \node[my node style] (A) at (0,0) {this is node A};
  \draw[arrows=->] (L) -- (A);

  \node (M) at (-1.5in,-1in) {not the expected effect};
  \node[my node style=-60,text width=2in] (B) at (0,-1in) {this is node B which I expected to be rotated $-60^\circ$};
  \draw[arrows=->] (M) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for nice approach.  But this doesn't really resolve the problem that I have of needing to override a previously set rotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can parametrize your style by setting `[my node style/.style={rotate=#1,draw}]` and then call the style with the parameter that you need. (see pgf-manual 43.4.4)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[my node style/.style={rotate=#1,draw}]
\node (L) at (-1.5in,0) {using my node style};
\node[my node style=60] (A) at (0,0) {this is node A};
\draw[arrows=->] (L) -- (A);

\node (M) at (-1.5in,-1in) {not the expected effect};
\node[my node style=-60,text width=2in] (B) at (0,-1in) {this is node B which I expected  to be rotated $-60^\circ$};
\draw[arrows=->] (M) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX and thanks for answering here. But I am afraid, your answer does not differ enough from the [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212900) provided by Ignasi. If there is a difference, which I haven't seen, please elaborate more on this. Thanks you.